# Limitations of SharePoint OOTB forms against infopath

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

what are the limitations of OOTB SP forms against InfoPath forms?

can we create multiple views on the same list using OOTB forms? how about rules, change the width height etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The InfoPath form surpasses the default SharePoint form in the following:

- Validation and Verification
- Rules
- No Code solutions
- Cascading drop-downs without JavaScript
- Quick development/deployment
- Suitable for development by power users.
- Form layout organization
- Conditional Formatting
- Can receive from / send to multiple data sources

---

**Can we create multiple views on the same list using OOTB forms?**

- NO. you can only create the normal list views, not form vies

**How about rules?**

- No automation rules, but you can use the column validation setting or workflows to manage rules.

**Change the width height?**

- No, each new field will be added one below one based on your column order settings. Meanwhile, you can use the SharePoint designer and CSS to customize it.

---

**[Update based on comment]**

**PowerApps** and **Microsoft Flow** are the successors to InfoPath and SharePoint Designer for many common business scenarios, especially custom forms used in SharePoint lists.

Check the details at [Sharepoint designer 2016 and InfoPath 2016 in sharepoint server 2016/SharePoint Online, what’re the alternatives?](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/05/06/did-you-consider-powerapps-is-a-replacement-for-sharepoint-designer-and-infopath-in-sharepoint/)

Comment: so what are the other alternative to infopath ?

Comment: PowerApps and Microsoft Flow are the successors to InfoPath and SharePoint Designer for many common business scenarios, especially custom forms used on SharePoint lists. check the above-attached article for more details

Comment: Can we create multiple views on the same list using OOTB forms? You create multiple forms on a list. i.e. Views

Comment: Hi @iOnline247 , The OP asked "Is the InfoPath Views functionality is available or can be achieved in the default SP Forms as OOTB!" **So** If you checked the **Views** and Views Switch based on the Rule in Infopath form,you will confirm it's impossible to achieve the same functionality in the normal forms as **OOTB** For more details about InfoPath views please check https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-delete-and-switch-views-pages-in-a-form-89677734-2a77-47fa-8c04-d83fd24f18c2 Please don't rush your decision to downvote the answer before reading the question and answer carefully  :)

Comment: I appreciate your comment, but still disagree with you. ;)

Answer (score 4):

OOTB is what you see is what you get. You can configure the forms if you want in SPD (SharePoint designer) to have what you want in the forms like you suggest. or directly edit it which i dont suggest ;)

do you mean multiple forms like edit, add? or views of the list?

as for infopath yes it can do a lot more than OOTB but its being phased out so why use it? You should be embracing "Forms" / "PowerApps" and "Flow", these newish 365 applications should be used to create new forms and workflows. You could still use SPD for now or keep on using it as i dont think its going any time soon. Because both apps are still new they wont have full functionality but should be able do what you want.

Comment: "Forms" as in like new forms you see by clicking the corner of the webpage? . I can only see options to create surveys  etc. how can we associate it with a SP list.

Comment: if you were to use sharepoint designer, you would connect to the site that contains the survey. At its core its just a list (depending on what servery your using ;) ) - connect by going to "open site", under "lists and libraries" select the survey and then you should be able to add a new forms to the survey with type edit, delete or new and if its default or not. You can assign actions as-well that goes to forms or triggers workflows from the item drop down menu.